# Trying to split following url

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm trying to split following URL:

```
http://www.store.com/products.aspx/Books/The-happy-donkey
```

in order to get only `store`.

How can this be done?

Comment: Read this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split

Comment: This can also help: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL

Answer (score 2):

To do something as generic as possible I'd do something like:

```js
const url = new URL('http://www.store.com/products.aspx/Books/The-happy-donkey');
const { hostname } = url;
const domain = hostname.match(/^www\.(\w+)\.com/);
console.log(domain[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code

```
//window.location.href
let str = "http://www.store.com/products.aspx/Books/The-happy-donkey";
const words = str.split('.');
console.log(words[1]);
```